# Wine & PHP-gd conflict over libgd3

Tags: wine, dependencies, php

I initially had wine installed on my Ubuntu 22.04 through `sudo apt install wine`
I then tried to install PHP 8.2 along with a set of its extensions by running

```
sudo apt-get install -y php8.2-cli php8.2-common php8.2-fpm php8.2-mysql php8.2-zip php8.2-gd php8.2-mbstring php8.2-curl php8.2-xml php8.2-bcmath
```

Only to get the following error:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php8.2-gd : Depends: libgd3 (>= 2.3.3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I then tried to resolve the issue with libgd3 manually by install it through `sudo apt-get install libgd3`, yet this message was shown:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libgd3:i386 libgphoto2-6:i386 libwine:i386 wine32:i386
```

I proceeded with the installation anyways, and then checked if there were any issues with wine by running `wine --version` and got this output:

```
it looks like wine32 is missing, you should install it.
as root, please execute "apt-get install wine32"
wine-6.0.3 (Ubuntu 6.0.3~repack-1)
```

And when I ran `sudo apt-get install wine32`:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgphoto2-6:i386 : Depends: libgd3:i386 (>= 2.1.0~alpha~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So I tried installing libgd3:i386 by running `sudo apt-get install libgd3:i386` this time:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libgd3 libgphoto2-6 libwine wine wine64
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libgd3:i386
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 5 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 150 kB of archives.
After this operation, 562 MB disk space will be freed.
```

which entirely got rid of wine.
Anyone familiar with this paradox?